# Using linux system() function C++ beagle bone issue

Tags: c, linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I have searched around but can't find an answer to my problem.

I am cross compiling a C++ application for the beagle bone black and wish to use the linux system() function as follows :

*system("echo DM-GPIO-Test > $SLOTS");*

It is to add a device overlay to control GPIO pins. The echo command "echo DM-GPIO-Test > $SLOTS" works fine when executed directly on the terminal on the beagle bone from anywhere. SLOTS is an environmental variable I defined and DM-GPIO-Test-00A0.dtb0 is in /lib/firmware

I get the following error on execution of the c++ application however:

*"sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent"*

Is it incorrect to call the system function like I did ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `system("echo $SLOTS");` display anything? As a side note, there is nothing C++-specific in your example.

Comment: Are you running it with the same user you use within the shell?

Comment: No, it doesn't display anything doing system("echo $SLOTS");. The error disappears however. I'm running the the application using sudo. I Tried putting sudo in the string in the system function too but nothing. @ DYZ, yes, you're right, nothing C++ specific actually. It's C

Comment: Don't use `system` in this case. You should use `fopen`+`fprintf`+`fclose` and get the `$SLOTS` path using `getenv("SLOTS")`, check that and pass it to `fopen`

Comment: Your question has been downvoted, because it lacks some [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `system("echo DM-GPIO-Test > $SLOTS");`

This smells bad and should be avoided.

What you probably want is to write a string in a file given by your `SLOTS` environment variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)). For that particular use, you don't need to fork any `/bin/sh` process (which is what [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) does). You could simply fetch that environment variable using [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html).

So you might try:

```
const char*slotspath = getenv("SLOTS");
if (!slotspath) {
   fprintf(stderr, "no SLOTS\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
FILE* fslots = fopen(slotspath, "w");
if (!fslots) {  perror(slotspath); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
fputs("DM-GPIO-Test\n", fslots);
fclose(fslots), fslots = NULL;
```

Be aware that the environment of your program -assuming it is started by some other utility (or from [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd))- is probably different (and smaller) than your interactive environment.

Perhaps your `slotspath` should not come from your environment, but from some configuration file under `/etc/` (that your program should parse), or some program argument.

So I suggest to define the format of some configuration file and parse it, and get your `slotspath` from it.

Comment: Thanks for that! Lots of stuff I wasn't aware of. Any idea why such a question like I asked gets a -4 down vote?

Answer (score 2):

> No, it doesn't display anything doing system("echo $SLOTS")

In this case the environment variable `SLOTS` is simply unset/empty in the environment used by your application. Depending on your use case you either need to set it before you start the binary, or using `setenv()`, or replacing it directly in the string you pass to `system()`. If you expect the variable to be set in any of the user's profile settings you need to be aware of the different behaviour of your shell (e. g. [bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION)) at invocation, and place it in the right file, or create a wrapper script that sets it.

```
$ cat .profile 
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
[...]
```

A good idea would also be to check it for valid values in your application prior to the `system()` call, using `getenv()` to obtain it and `assert`ing if it doesn't match the requirements.

Be aware that it is best practice to enclose shell variables containing strings into double quotes, in case they contain spaces, and the identifier into curly brackets, to avoid ambiguities:

```
system("echo DM-GPIO-Test > \"${SLOTS}\"");
```

And as Basile points out in a separate answer, avoiding invocation of the shell and handling the logic of writing the file completely in C would even be more powerful regarding the handling of errors and special cases, but also results in more code (which could contain bugs of its own...).

Comment: Ok it seems so. Why does this happen do you know?My application is executed from /root . If I can do echo $SLOTS directly in root from the terminal, it shows that it's set, but not from application. Thanks

Comment: Lacking a crystal ball I don't know why it isn't there. It's your job to find out where it is supposed to be set, and why this isn't done in the environment your application is started in.

Comment: Ah ok. I have environmental variables set in  ~/.profile . I guess then they will only be noticed when in a shell session? I should have them set elsewhere for what I want? Sorry, i'm not a Linux expert